# How can I access elasticsearch from a static ip?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu using Hyper-V. I setup elasticsearch in my ubuntu virtual machine. How can I run elasticsearch from a static ip

1. sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
2. sudo apt-get install nginx
3. Sudo systemctl enable nginx
4. sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
5. sudo apt-get update
6. wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.10.0-amd64.deb
7. installed elasticsearch
8. Sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

I am able to run elasticsearch on a the local machine

```
-------Network-----
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
```

When I go to the browser and connect to localhost:9200, it successfully finds elasticsearch

I want to access elasticsearch through a static ip.  For example: 192.168.1.150:9200

I tried

```
-------Network-----
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP
network.host: 192.168.1.150
http.port: 9200
```

I run 'sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service'

I get error
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

Is there a way to accomplish this?
I want to be able to run elasticsearch, logstash, and kibana on the static ip

journalctl -xe

```
- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 20 14:22:52 ateet-Virtual-Machine systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 14:22:52 ateet-Virtual-Machine systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 9061 and the job result is failed.
Nov 20 14:22:52 ateet-Virtual-Machine sudo[45417]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

elasticsearch.log

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to 192.168.1.150:[9300-9400]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
```

Thanks

Comment: If elasticsearch failed on startup it will have logged an error message. You have not told us what error it logged. What errors do you see from elasticsearch when you run "journalctl -xe"?

Comment: i just updated it

Comment: OK, those do not help. You will need to find the elasticsearch logs, which are probably under /var/log/elasticsearch.

Comment: I had to cut some of elasticsearch.log....it was to long to post

Comment: please share complete elasticsearch.yml file. and netstat -anpl |grep 9200 and netstat -anpl |grep 9300. and response of ifconfig. elasticsearch cannot bind IP or port. maybe some process get the ports or you dont have 192.168.1.150 on your interface.